# Last iteration of for loop if (something equals something)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works, but gives me results of all cases when `Item === CheckId` in the array. How to get only last time? `(Item === CheckId).length` results in undefined. Also I tried to create variable outside of `if` statement and increase it inside of `if` statement. But it increased only once.

```
        function updateDirections() {

                    $('.ui-selected').each(function(i, obj) {
                        textArea = $("#fname").val();
                        textArea = textArea.split(';');
                        //textArea.replace(/\(.+?,\ \{/, "");
                        //console.log((textArea[4].toLowerCase().indexOf(this.id) >= 0));
                        //textArea = textArea.map(function(w){ return +!!~this.id.indexOf(w) });
                        //console.log(obj.id);

                        Item = this.id;
                        var arrayLength = textArea.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                            CheckId = textArea[i];
                            CheckId = CheckId.match(/\(.+?,\ \{/)
                            CheckId = String(CheckId).replace(/\(/g, "").replace(/,/g, "").replace(/ /g, "").replace(/\{/g, "");

                            if (Item === CheckId) {
                                console.log(textArea[i]);
                            }

                        }


                    });
                }
```

Comment: `textArea.split(';');` ? it is for string but you already have array

Comment: You are setting Item to 'string' and CheckId to 'string'.  Your loop is doing nothing with textArea.  Given textArea being what it is before you do anything with it, what are you trying to do?

Comment: This code won't work, array prototype does not have a `split` function. Also what do you mean when you say you want to do `(Item === CheckId).length`. You are checking length of a boolean in that case ...

Comment: You should share your actual code

Comment: Ok, I tried to simplify my code. Here is the actual. There is a javascript in the textarea, that i want to modify on draging some div. "updateDirections" fires when div is dragging. The code is works, but i want to get only last iteration of console.log(textArea[i]); not all of it

Comment: Instead of just showing code that 'does not work', can you please clearly explain what you have and the desired result?

Comment: So you want the above code to execute only once when you stop dragging?

Comment: Jose Rodrigues whell it' doesn really matter. I just want to get only last time function works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want to achieve, but if you want the value of the last `console.log`, you can indeed use a variable :

```
Item = this.id;
var arrayLength = textArea.length,
    lastValue = null; // here is the variable
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    CheckId = textArea[i];
    CheckId = CheckId.match(/\(.+?,\ \{/)
    CheckId = String(CheckId).replace(/\(/g, "").replace(/,/g, "").replace(/ /g, "").replace(/\{/g, "");

    if (Item === CheckId) {
        lastValue = textArea[i];
    }

}
// do anything you want with lastValue
```

Comment: Thanl you very much!